# Camera following instantiated object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple gun in Unity but for some reason as soon as the Bullet is instantiated the camera starts following it. The code for the shooting doesn't even mention the camera so I don't understand what's happening.

Shooting Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform bulletSpawnPoint;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public float bulletSpeed = 10f;
    public GameObject character;
    Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)){
            var bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletSpawnPoint.position, bulletSpawnPoint.rotation);
            Rigidbody rb = bullet.AddComponent<Rigidbody>() as Rigidbody;
            rb.velocity = transform.forward * bulletSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        transform.position = character.transform.position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question:

```
var bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab ...
```

From [your comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75652473/camera-following-instantiated-object#comment133466944_75652700):

> when I initiated the bullet it also created a Camera

it sounds like your `bulletPrefab` has a camera attached to it. Instead of looking for a camera every time you instantiate the bullet, just go to the prefab and remove the camera there instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell exactly what the problem is without seeing the rest of the code, but i suspect the culprit to be:

```
transform.position = character.transform.position;
```

I think this line is setting the position of the object that this script is attached to (presumably the camera) to be the same as the position of the character. So when you instantiate the bullet, the camera (or whatever object this script is attached to) is also moved to the same position as the character, and thus it looks like the camera is following the bullet.

as a debbuging step you could try to be in the scene view instead of the game view

Comment: This script is attached to the gun. That piece of code you mentioned is moving the gun to the same place that the player is. The camera is never mentioned in this script.

Comment: I see. In that case, it's possible that the issue is with your camera setup. If your camera is a child object of the gun or the bullet, it will move along with them when they are spawned.

Comment: Turns out the problem was that when I initiated the bullet it also created a Camera and set it as the default. I just deleted that before adding velocity to the bullet. Thanks for the help though.